# Sequelize belongToMany association not working through table

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize on PostgreSQL to store users that belong to organizations. The organizations own devices that the users can access. So in essence, users also own devices through their organizations.

I set it up that each device is associated with an organization using the organization_id as well each user is associated with an organization using an organization_id. I'm trying to set this up with Sequelize to read it properly. I'm trying my best not to resort to writing a custom query, but it's okay if I have to in the end.

I'm trying to get all devices associated with a user ID. Sequelize prints out this crazy query with an error when I try to run the findAll(...) command. It outputs this query and then an empty set:

```
SELECT 
    "receiver"."receiver_id" AS "id", 
    "receiver"."organization_id" AS "organizationID", 
    "receiver"."identifier", 
    "receiver"."secret", 
    "receiver"."iterations", 
    "receiver"."sodium", 
    "receiver"."algorithm", 
    "receiver"."created", 
    "receiver"."modified", 
    "receiver"."deleted", 
    "receiver"."organization_id", 
    "users"."user_id" AS "users.id", 
    "users"."password" AS "users.password", 
    "users"."sodium" AS "users.sodium", 
    "users"."email" AS "users.email", 
    "users"."organization_id" AS "users.organizationID", 
    "users"."iterations" AS "users.iterations", 
    "users"."algorithm" AS "users.algorithm", 
    "users"."created" AS "users.created", 
    "users"."modified" AS "users.modified", 
    "users"."deleted" AS "users.deleted", 
    "users"."organization_id" AS "users.organization_id", 
    "users.organizations"."created" AS "users.organizations.created", 
    "users.organizations"."modified" AS "users.organizations.modified", 
    "users.organizations"."organization_id" AS "users.organizations.organization_id" 
FROM "receivers" AS "receiver" 
INNER JOIN (
    "organizations" AS "users.organizations" 
    INNER JOIN "users" AS "users" 
    ON "users"."user_id" = "users.organizations"."organization_id") 
ON "receiver"."receiver_id" = "users.organizations"."organization_id" 
AND ("users"."deleted" IS NULL AND "users"."user_id" = 2) 
WHERE "receiver"."deleted" IS NULL;
```

How can I be writing the definitions or code better?

Thanks so much.

My table definitions in Sequelize:

```
var organization = sequelize.define( 'organization', {
    'id': {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        field: 'organization_id',
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    'name' : {
        type:  Sequelize.STRING( 256 ),
        field: 'name',
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true
        }
    }
}, {
    'createdAt' : 'created',
    'updatedAt' : 'modified',
    'deletedAt' : 'deleted',
    'tableName' : 'organizations',
    'paranoid'  : true
} );

var user = sequelize.define( 'user', {
    'id': {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        field: 'user_id',
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    'password': {
        type: Sequelize.STRING( 64 ),
        field: 'password',
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true
        }
    },
    'sodium': {
        type: Sequelize.STRING( 64 ),
        field: 'sodium',
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true
        }
    },
    'email' : {
        type:  Sequelize.STRING( 64 ),
        field: 'email',
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true
        }
    },
    'organizationID' : {
        type:  Sequelize.BIGINT,
        field: 'organization_id',
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true
        }
    },
    'iterations' : {
        type:  Sequelize.INTEGER,
        field: 'iterations',
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true
        }
    },
    'algorithm' : {
        type:  Sequelize.STRING( 8 ),
        field: 'algorithm',
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 'sha256'
    }
}, {
    'createdAt' : 'created',
    'updatedAt' : 'modified',
    'deletedAt' : 'deleted',
    'tableName' : 'users',
    'paranoid'  : true
} );

var receiver = sequelize.define( 'receiver', {
    'id': {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        field: 'receiver_id',
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    'organizationID': {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        field: 'organization_id',
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true
        }
    },
    'identifier': {
        type: Sequelize.STRING( 64 ),
        field: 'identifier',
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true
        }
    },
    'secret' : {
        type:  Sequelize.STRING( 64 ),
        field: 'secret',
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true
        }
    },
    'iterations' : {
        type:  Sequelize.INTEGER,
        field: 'iterations',
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true
        }
    },
    'sodium': {
        type: Sequelize.STRING( 64 ),
        field: 'sodium',
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true
        }
    },
    'algorithm' : {
        type:  Sequelize.STRING( 8 ),
        field: 'algorithm',
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 'sha256'
    }
}, {
    'createdAt' : 'created',
    'updatedAt' : 'modified',
    'deletedAt' : 'deleted',
    'tableName' : 'receivers',
    'paranoid'  : true
} );

// Organizations have users and users have organizations
organization.hasMany( user, { 'foreignKey' : 'organization_id' } );
user.belongsTo( organization, { 'foreignKey' : 'organization_id' } );

// Organizations have receivers
organization.hasMany( receiver, { 'foreignKey' : 'organization_id' } );
receiver.belongsTo( organization, { 'foreignKey' : 'organization_id' } );

// Receivers to users
user.belongsToMany( receiver, { 'through' : 'organizations', 'foreignKey' : 'organization_id' } );
receiver.belongsToMany( user, { 'through' : 'organizations', 'foreignKey' : 'organization_id' } );
```

The code I'm using to query:

```
// Get the devices for this person
db.receiver.findAll( {
    'include' : [
                {
                    'model' : db.user,
                    'where' : { 'id' : 2 }
                }
            ]
} )
.complete( function( error, result ) {
    if( error ) {
        console.log( error );
    }
    else {
        console.log( result );
    }
} );
```

Comment: why in you userdevice table you have both userID and origanizationID?

Comment: Thank you for writing that comment. It made me realize that I had extra code in there and some issues. That was part of a separate table that didn't relate to this issue. I hope what I wrote is more clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, what it does it selects the user that matches the where statement, and includes organization associated with it, which in it's turn includes devices associated with it, so you should end up with devices associated with the user.

```
// Organizations have users
user.belongsTo(organization);
// Organizations have receivers
receiver.belongsTo(organization);


// Get the devices for this person
db.user.find( {
    'include' : [
        {model: db.organization,
         include: [model: db.receiver]
        }
    ]
    'where' : { 'id' : 2 }
} )
.complete( function( error, result ) {
    if( error ) {
        console.log( error );
    }
    else {
        console.log( result );
    }
} );
```

if you are using underscore id field names like organization_id, you can specify "underscored: true" when creating the model, so you don't have to specify foreign key field when creating associations.

Comment: Good suggestion. Thank you! I followed what you said and instead selecting the user and including the organization and then the receiver, I did the find on the receiver included the organization and then the user, then I did a where on the user include with the ID. Either way, the query it uses seems rather hacky, but if it works it works I suppose! Thanks again.

Comment: @mikealeonetti glad it worked for you! just want to know why did you decide to do the reverse selection? i mean receiver, then organization, then user with where statement?

Comment: My goal mainly was simply to get all of the receiver devices that a user could be associated with. I don't really need information about the organizations or the users when fetching. So somehow it just makes more sense to me to perform the find/select on the receivers table to get those first. Otherwise I'd have to get the result in the find, get the organization, then get the receivers. If this makes sense anyways :D.